# Javascript function who return length of html?

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript, is there a way that I can determine the size of a document excluding any markup?

Comment: What do you mean length of **HTML** without *tags?*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question for clarity to the best of my ability. Please check my edits to be sure that your question still reflects the problem you are trying to solve. In the future, try to be much more clear and specific when asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '').length
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is something like `$(document).text().length`. It's not going to be completely exact, but it's going to be a good aproximation.